# How can I get the for loop to stop to stop running and proceed to the next methid once the program has been executed in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

The code is first getting the user to input the number of students in a class. Then the system will allow the user to add the names of those students. After which the user can assign a mark and credit hours for subjects for each of those students. Once the marks and credit hours have been entered for each student, the system should then calculate the GPA. However, the system continues to run the loop and it does not execute and display the GPA. Can I be assisted as the why this loop does not execute:

```java
public class testing1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int result;
        String[] names = new String[100];
        System.out.println("Enter number of students (Must be between 1-50)");
        result = in .nextInt();
        System.out.println("Thank you, Please enter the names for the " + result + " Students");
        int nameCount = 0;
        while (nameCount < result) {
            System.out.println("Enter First Name: ");
            String s1 = in .next();
            System.out.println("The students name is" + " " + s1);
            System.out.println();
            names[nameCount] = s1;
            nameCount++;
        }
        double[][] marks = new double[100][2];
        int[][] credits = new int[100][2];
        double[] gpa = new double[100];
        String[] subjects = {"Math", "Science",};
        int cnt = 0;
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        gpa[cnt] = 0;
        int totalCredits = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < subjects.length; j++) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Please enter " + names[i] +"'s mark in "  + subjects[j] + ": ");
                marks[cnt][i] = s1.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Please enter " + names[i] +"'s Credit hours for "+ subjects[j] + ": ");
                credits[cnt][i] = s1.nextInt();
                totalCredits += credits[cnt][i];
                gpa[cnt] += marks[cnt][i] * credits[cnt][i];
            }
            cnt++;
        }
        gpa[cnt] /= totalCredits;
        System.out.printf("GPA of :" + names[cnt] + " is %.2f.", gpa[cnt]);
        return;
    }
}
```

Below is the output when I run the system from the beginning:

```
Enter number of students (Must be between 1-50)
2
Thank you, Please enter the names for the 2 Students
Enter First Name: 
Alan
The students name is Alan

Enter First Name: 
Bob
The students name is Bob



Please enter Alan's mark in Math: 
12
Please enter Alan's Credit hours for Math: 
12


Please enter Alan's mark in Science: 
12
Please enter Alan's Credit hours for Science: 
12


Please enter Bob's mark in Math: 
12
Please enter Bob's Credit hours for Math: 
12


Please enter Bob's mark in Science: 
12
Please enter Bob's Credit hours for Science: 
12


Please enter null's mark in Math: 
12
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
    at testing1.testing1.main(testing1.java:59)
```

Comment: How do you know that it "continues to run the loop"? Please add the output to your question. By the way, you never use `j` as an array subscript.

Comment: Does this actually crash, and print a stack trace, after processing the first two students?  That's not the same thing as "the system continues to run the loop".

Comment: Below is the output that I get:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
 at testing1.testing1.main(testing1.java:59)

Comment: I have edited my question and included the full output as well

Comment: @KivanIlangakoon, I've edited my answer after you've changed the question. Please, check it out. :)

Comment: Everywhere that you wrote `[cnt][i]` it should have been `[i][j]`.  You don't need `cnt` at all, because it's always the same as `i`.  Also, when you're asking people for help, you should give them ALL the available information initially, not release it in installments.  Otherwise, we tend to waste our time.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem thanks, but it still gives me the same error message

Comment: And what is "it" now? You need to update the code in your question if you change it.

Answer (score 0):

## Update due to the question has changed

In the first loop you're iterating over the whole array of names. You also need a `i < nameCount` condition because the arrays have data from the begining until as many students as the user has entered. So, the condition will be as follow:

```
//other code
for (int i = 0; i < names.length && i < nameCount; i++) {
    //other code
}
```

---

If you want to stop a loop, then you can set to true some condition variable and break the loop depending on its state. Something like:

```
for (...) {
    //sentences
    if (someCondition)
        break;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's not the problem.  See my most recent comment under the question.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Well, I think adding `i < nameCount` to the condition makes the loop to stop before it gets OutOfBounds due to the `marks` array access at position 2. Because @Kivan defines it as `double[][] marks = new double[100][2];`. So, in the 3rd iteration it throws the exception.
Why do say that's not the problem?

Comment: @LeoTapia the exception is because `i` is being used as an index where it should be `j`.

Comment: Because `i` can still get greater than 2, even with your fix.  The correct fix is NOT to use `i` as the second array index.  It should be `j` (which is only ever 0 or 1, when there are two subjects).

Comment: Why you said "`i` can still get greater than 2". That's not possible with my proposed condition `i < names.length && i < nameCount`. `i` is limitted by `nameCount` entered at the begining. If the user enters `2` as number of students, why would `i` get greater than 2?.
What I see is that the code block corresponding to the for loop that defines `i` will get executed just 2 times, when `i=0` and `i=1`. When `i=2` the condition evaluates to false, so the code won't access any array with a invalid index. His problem is `it does not execute and display the GPA`. My proposed condition fixes it :)

Answer (score 0):

Notes after the code.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testing2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of students (between 1-50): ");
        int result = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        String[] names = new String[result];
        System.out.println("Thank you, please enter the names for the " + result + " students.");
        for (int i = 0; i < result; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Enter student %d first name: ", (i + 1));
            names[i] = in.nextLine();
        }
        double[] gpa = new double[result];
        String[] subjects = {"Math", "Science",};
        double[][] marks = new double[result][subjects.length];
        int[][] credits = new int[result][subjects.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < result; i++) {
            int totalCredits = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < subjects.length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("Please enter %s's mark in %s: ", names[i], subjects[j]);
                marks[i][j] = in.nextDouble();
                System.out.printf("Please enter %s's credit hours for %s: ", names[i], subjects[j]);
                credits[i][j] = in.nextInt();
                totalCredits += credits[i][j];
                gpa[i] += marks[i][j] * credits[i][j];
            }
            gpa[i] /= totalCredits;
            System.out.printf("GPA of %s is %.2f%n", names[i], gpa[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

- You only need one `Scanner` object. No need to create a new `Scanner` each time you want to get input from the user.
- Declare variables when you require them.
- You can use `result` to declare your `names` array. Then you can use a `for` loop to get the names.
- No need for variable `s1`. Assign the value returned by method `nextLine` directly to the `names` array.
- You can also use `result` when you declare the other arrays, including `marks`, `credits` and `gpa`. In fact, you can use any expression that returns an `int` result for any dimension of an array.
- No need for variables `nameCount` and `cnt`.
- All calculations need to be done within the nested `for` loops.
- You need to reset `totalCredits` for each student.

Output from a sample run:

```
Enter number of students (between 1-50): 2
Thank you, please enter the names for the 2 students.
Enter student 1 first name: George
Enter student 2 first name: Edson
Please enter George's mark in Math: 2.0
Please enter George's credit hours for Math: 3
Please enter George's mark in Science: 4.0
Please enter George's credit hours for Science: 2
GPA of George is 2.80
Please enter Edson's mark in Math: 2.67
Please enter Edson's credit hours for Math: 3
Please enter Edson's mark in Science: 1.33
Please enter Edson's credit hours for Science: 4
GPA of Edson is 1.90
```